# Why it's giving me True as output as "None" is not a boolean type... so why "not None = True"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried this code to see what happens , but i cant get the logic behind it , i was expecting an error ... just for curiosity

## python2.7

```
x = not None
print x
```

Answer (score 4):

When Python evaluates `not`, it tries to convert the value to a boolean.  In this case, None is "falsy" (https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html), so `not None` evaluates to `True`.

So, `x = not None` is equivalent to `x = True` - i.e. you're assigning the variable x to be True.

Comment: then why this code giving me output as else statement 

if (not None) == False:
    print "same"
else :
    print "something is fishy"

Comment: because `(not None) == False`, evaluates to `False` (since `True != False`), sending you to the `else` block.

Comment: thanks for the answer i missed that fact (not None= True)

Answer (score 1):

Because `not` is a boolean type operator (a logical NOT), it converts None into a boolean. None as a boolean is False. The opposite of False, or `not None` is True, thus printing True.

```
>>> print(bool(None))
False

>>> print(not bool(None))
True
```

Comment: then why its executing else statement 
    if (not None) == False:
        print "same"
    else :
        print "something is fishy"

Comment: @ManojGoswami it will print 'something is fishy' because true doesn't equal false

Answer (score 0):

`None` evaluates to `False`. The opposite of `False` is `True`. Thus, the result of `not None` is `True`. The boolean type conversion happens automatically, similar to what happens in `3 + True`, which gives `4`.

Comment: but None and False are two totally different things.
None has type NoneType and value None
and True has type "Boolean" and value True

Comment: Booleans in python are generally very fluid in terms of type, many things can be implicitly cast into them (like `None`), and they can also be implicitly cast into other types like `int`.